# How should I find an average for data that randomly fluctuates?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, statistics

I have data for the temperature of a flame at a given height above the burner. The temperature fluctuates quite a bit (see figure), but there is definitely an "average" value that it tends to fluctuate around. Is there a good way to find this value? I'm using excel for data analysis.
[image]

Comment: Which column contains the temperature data? (A, B, C,...)

Comment: If you have the raw data you could simply just average in the time period where the fluctuations occur no?

Answer (score 0):

If that's your data, well, then that is it. Dont try to manipulate your data or methods to get what you want to see. Just take the average of each burner.

One other thing you could do is to look for the possible sources of variability on your measurements and try to reduce that variability to the minimum. Or you could just take measurements for a longer time, so you got more points to average, it should look less random.

Comment: The reason I collected this data was to design a thermal device, but I'm hoping to have a relatively stable number that I can begin my design with. For example, if I want to design a fin to operate at burner level 2, I'd like to know what the average temperature is (it looks like it's close to ~650 degrees C in the graph but I don't know how to mathematically prove this). Thanks for your tips so far!